# Duplicate key error after I DELETE rows then INSERT them back in in a transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I use the following pattern in a transaction:

```sql
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM table_a WHERE uuid = 'uuid';
INSERT INTO (uuid, value) VALUES ('uuid', 'value1'), ('uuid','value2')
COMMIT;
```

```sql
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE table_a (
    uuid uuid,
    value character varying(255) UNIQUE,
    CONSTRAINT table_a_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uuid, value)
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_value_unique ON table_a(value text_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_a_pkey ON table_a(uuid uuid_ops,value text_ops);
```

The lines inserted are the **same** as the ones that have been deleted.

Most of the time, it works fine, but sometimes I get this error I can't reproduce:

```
insert into "table_a" ("uuid", "value") values ($1, $2), ($3, $4) - duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_a_value_unique"
```

I'm wondering why that is, are lines in a transaction sometimes executed concurrently? Do I have to use `DEFERRED`?

Comment: No, the insert will not be executed concurrently with the delete.

Comment: as the error seems to depent on an prepared statement, it would be helpfull to see the code you use to executed the query.

Comment: Maybe `$1` and `$3` are the same?

Comment: can you check that all the key values are unique.

Comment: They are unique, sometimes it happens when I try to insert one row only.